# My bicycle shifter fails

Tags: shimano, shifter

In my bicycle the shifter Shimano st ef41 does not work.

It fails when I press it.  Tell me please and how to remove all wires from shifter.

[image: From https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney/ST-EF41-L.html]
<sub>Image from https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney/ST-EF41-L.html</sub>

Comment: You're certain it's the shifter that's at fault and not the derailleur?

Answer (score 1):

Your part number is for a combination brake/shift lever for a flat handlebar.

So there will be a cable for the brake, and a separate cable for the shifter.

If its on your left-hand that will be the front derailleur, and the right hand will go to the back. Which side goes to which brake depends on what area of the world you're in.

To remove the cables, trace them to the derailleur/brake and find the pinch bolt.  That could be a 6 sided bolt or it could be a 5mm hex socket.  Slack it off to let the cable move out.   You probably have to cut off any end-cap that covers the cut end.  Then draw the cable back through the outer housing to the shifter.

If the cable is chewed up then you might prefer to buy new cables.  They're not very expensive.

The gear cable is the thinner of the two, and the shifter part will have a plastic plug dust cover that threads into the body of the shifter.  A screwdriver can undo it gently, and then the shifter wire should push back through.  Your shifter will need to be in the most "relaxed" gear so press the thumb button a bunch to get there.

The brake cable is completely different.  If you pull the brake lever fully back, it will show where the brake cable is terminated.  Simply pull the cable back through and it will be fairly obvious.

Reassembly is basically the reverse process.  The trick is dialling in the brake and shifter so they work right again.

You might choose to replace the shifter with a stand-alone shifter, and then cut the faulty one off your existing unit.  That way you don't have to touch the brakes at all.

Good luck!  If you feel overwhelmed, do ask another question.